# Why does info exists always return 0 when checkin for the existence of a canva object (Tcl/Tk 8.5)

Tags: canvas, tcl, tk-toolkit

I tried the following test (see snippet hereunder):

and it always returns 0 regardless of the fact that the canvas object (the rectangle in this case) has been created (with "create") or deleted (with "delete").

Is there another way to check if a canvas object exists or has successfully been deleted in Tcl/Tk ?

Thanks !

Serge Hulne

```
    ############

    tk::canvas .can
    set r1 [.can create rect 30 10 120 80  -outline #fb0 -fill #fb0]
    set r2 [.can create rect 150 10 240 80 -outline #f50 -fill #f50]
    set r3 [.can create rect 270 10 370 80 -outline #05f -fill #05f]
    pack .can


    ##
    ##info exists does not work for canvas elements : it always returns 0
    set rcc [info exists $r2]
    puts "rcc = $rcc"


    if {[info exists $r2]} {
        puts "$r2 exists !"
       .can delete $r2
        puts [info exists $r2]
     } else {
         puts "$r2  does not exist !"
         set rc [info exists $r2]
         puts "rc = $rc  "
    }
    ##
    ##        
    wm title . "colors"
    wm geometry . 400x100+300+300

    ##########
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`info exists` is used to check whether a *variable* exists. A canvas widget is not a variable,  it is a *widget*.

As such, you need to use [`winfo exists`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/winfo.htm#M13) to check whether a canvas exists:

```
winfo exists .can
```

But then again, what you used as `r2` in your code is an item within the canvas, and there is no command to check its existence as far as I know. However, you can use `.can find all` to get a list of all the items in the canvas and compare it to `r2`:

```
% tk::canvas .can
% set r1 [.can create rect 30 10 120 80  -outline #fb0 -fill #fb0]
% set r2 [.can create rect 150 10 240 80 -outline #f50 -fill #f50]
% set r3 [.can create rect 270 10 370 80 -outline #05f -fill #05f]

% puts $r2
2  # Because it is the second item created
% .can find all
1 2 3
```

You can then do something like `lsearch -exact [.can find all] $r2` and if you get something not `-1`, know that this item exists.

---

Though if you use unique tags with your items, you can use `.can find withtag` to verify its existence:

```
% tk::canvas .can
% set r1 [.can create rect 30 10 120 80  -outline #fb0 -fill #fb0 -tags t1]
% set r2 [.can create rect 150 10 240 80 -outline #f50 -fill #f50 -tags t2]
% set r3 [.can create rect 270 10 370 80 -outline #05f -fill #05f -tags t3]

% .can find withtag t2
2  # which is equal to $r2
```

Comment: Or you can just check the length of `.can itemconfigure $r2`'s result list; if `$r2` doesn't refer to any item, it's empty.

Comment: @DonalFellows Nice, I didn't think about this!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks ! Since it returns a list the command is:          "if { [llength [.can itemconfigure $r2]] > 0 } {"